# Mongoose inside a promise change happens late

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

I am writing an API in NodeJS in which I use Mongoose and BlueBird. Regarding promise chain, my data was supposed to go through waterfall functions but it didn't. Let my example start with `getTagNames` to get some `JSON` , feeding data to `retrieveTag` to query and end up with `res.json()`.

```
exports.getTagValues = function (req, res) {
  var userId = req.params.uid;
  getTagNames(req, res)
    .then(retrieveTag)
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log('tags', data);
      res.json(200, data);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log('err', err);
      //handle Error
    })
}
```

Here is my toy data,

```
function getTagNames(req, res) {
  var userId = req.params.uid;
    return new Promise.resolve({
        'userId': userId,
        'variables': [
                { id: 1, name: 'hotel', type: 'String' },
                { id: 2, name: 'location', type: 'String' }
            ],
      })
}
```

The way I query data. After querying inside mongo, I check whether or not have a document with `userID`. In case not, insert and return document. Note `Tag` is my mongo model

```
function retrieveTag(data){
  Tag.findOne({'userId': data.userId})
    .exec()
    .then( function(tag){
      if (tag) {
        console.log('result', tag);
        // do something ...
        return tag;
      }
      else {
        var newTag = new Tag({
          advertiserId: advertiserId,
          variables: variables
        });
        newTag.save()
          .then(function () {
            console.log('newTag', newTag);
            return newTag;
          });
      }
    })
}
```

Here is my result (`userId` is `1`), my expectation is `console.log('tags', data);` occurs after all then `data` should not be `undefined`

```
tags undefined
GET /api/tag/values/1 200 3ms
newTag { __v: 0,
  userId: '1',
  _id: 581b96090e5916cf3f5112fe,
  variables: 
   [ { type: 'String', name: 'hotel', id: 1 },
     { type: 'String', name: 'location', id: 2 } ] }
```

My question is how can I fix it. If there's some unclear, please help me correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation is a bit unclear, but if I follow you right you loose data in the promise resolvement chain.

When reading your code, I notice that `retrieveTag` does not return the Mongoose promise. To let `.then` in `getTagValues` use the data found in `retrieveTag`.

So change to this:

```
function retrieveTag(data){
  return Tag.findOne({'userId': data.userId})
    .exec()
    .then( function(tag){
      ...
    })
}
```